# PHP/Symfony/Ajax/Apache - Handling temporary files of unfinished registrations or caching in browser

Tags: php, ajax, apache, symfony

### The Situation:

I have a page on which a user can enter deatils and apply for a job (multiple pages, not just one form). During the registration process a user can upload files that will be stored in a temporary folder on the server and will be attached to the application later. During the application process the user can upload additional files, delete those he uploaded etc.

Once the registration is finished successfully, the final files are moved to a user specific folder of which I store the path in my database so it is attached to the application - everything's fine.

### The Problem:

If the registration is not finished successfully (basically it has been cancelled), but files were uploaded, how do I remove those files in a smart way?

When the application has been finished successfully, the active session will be closed. If the application has not been finished, the session will time out and no user has access to those files anymore.

### Thoughts:

Now there are a couple of ideas I can think of, but I am not sure, which one is the smartest. The upload will be handled via AJAX. I want the file to be uploaded or at least stored when they are added to the application, so they will be attached, even if the user moves them on it's harddrive during the process:

1) Clean up after session has timed out (custom session handler)

2) Store files in browser and only upload them on completion of the application

3) Use a cron job that deletes files older than X days

4) Serialize files into session which will be cleaned automatically without any modifications.

Ideally I want the temporary files to be gone once the process has finished or has been cancelled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store files with upload time in temporary table in database. On completion move files to another (target) table. In cron/database job delete records from temporary table older than 1 day.

You can achieve same result with files. Make temp directory, each day create subdirectory and store files in it. eg.

```
temp/20150911/some_unique_filename.pdf
```

In session store full path to file. On completion move files to target directory. In cron delete directories older than 1 day.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, that's answer 3), but is this really the smartest way? I was wondering if there's a way quicker and more explicit to clean up. I mean, I don't think that someone is working on his/her application for more than 24h but technically it is possible to delete files then, that are still needed. If the cleanup would be connected to the session (or one would not send the files at all in way 2) only files can be deleted that have no reference to them anywhere. Maybe this is over the top and cron-job is best practice - that's why I am asking ;-)

Comment: You can use custom php session handler, but it occasionaly could miss some gc runs.

Comment: Great idea! Additionally I could also modify the gc itself. While saying this: What about serializing the files into the session itself? Then gc and everything else does not have to be modified at all. I will add this as the 4th option in my question.